# What are the default utility on centos we can use to read regular file inside .jar without extracting it?

Tags: bash, centos, sh

I'm trying to fetch a regular file content from a jar without extracting it.

example: unzip -p xxxx.jar somefile(regular file)

But unzip is not a default installed on CentOS. Do we have any utility for get the text without extracting .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have jdk installed. For example, jdk1.8.0_74-1.8.0_74-fcs.x86_64.

Just run **jar tf file.jar** to see file contents:

```
$ jar tf tomcat-juli.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/apache/juli/AsyncFileHandler$LogEntry.class
org/apache/juli/AsyncFileHandler$LoggerThread.class
org/apache/juli/AsyncFileHandler.class
....
enter code here
```

And then you may extract separate file (or some files space separated) with **jar xf file.jar file_to_extract1 file_to_extract2**:

```
$ jar xf tomcat-juli.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
$ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.1
Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

This way is acceptable for normal text files (txt, doc, xml, etc.), but not .class files because they are binary.

Comment: I don't want to extract the the jar file but want to see the file content within it.
Ex. unzip -p tomcat-juli.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Also need the default installed package.